# To determine a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been trying to solve the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \ln\left (\frac {\ln^2 (\sin x)}{\pi^2+\ln^2 (\sin x)}\right) \frac {\ln \cos x}{\tan x} dx$$
I tried substituting for $\frac {\ln^2 (\sin x)}{\pi^2+\ln^2 (\sin x)}$ and using the properties of definite integrals, but I am not able to proceed with the integral as the $\ln \cos x$ term doesn't get substituted. Is there any other trick that I can employ?

Comment: from where did you got this integral?

Comment: Oh I saw it on a forum a couple of days ago and wanted to work on it.

Comment: @Artemisia, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985686/integral-contest

Comment: Oh I found it on quora haha. I guess someone was trying to solve it on there :/

Comment: This problem has been stolen, [the Prosecutor General](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCMDBqHa78Y) has started an investigation into this grave matter.

Comment: Erm... Someone posted the question on quora and I saw it. The person who posted the question here is the same person who posted it on quora. Huh?

Comment: @Artemisia Yes, indeed. It's me. Sorry for closing your OP. Please no hurt feeling. Cheers! ٩(˘◡˘ )

Comment: @CountIblis Are you Ukrainian? If so, I'm apologized if my ava on Brilliant.org or info of my profile makes you uncomfortable

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova No, it's actually quite a fun profile! While I'm not from the region, I would guess a little humor would not be bad :) .

Comment: @CountIblis Oh my bad. I had bad days recently concerning to my recent OP. I was not fully aware with your joke & I thought you tried to make fun of me. I'm really sorry for that ≧◠‿◠≦✌