# Clarifying a step in an integration solution

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985686/integral-contest), the first two steps in computing the integral are

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
=&\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0\ln(1-e^{-2x})\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{\pi^2+x^2}\right)\ {\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\Bigg{|}_{a=0}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}\int^\infty_0x^ae^{-2nx}\ {\rm d}x+\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}\int^\infty_0e^{-2nx}\ln(\pi^2+x^2)\ {\rm d}x
\end{align}
I am stuck, however, on seeing what was done to show that these two lines are equivalent.  Could someone add a couple of steps in between, or give the name of the process?

Comment: $$x^a = e^{a \log{x}}$$

Comment: @RonGordon, I suppose I should clarify - I ask for the intermediate steps because I am especially curious to know how the summation and differentiation arose.