# Closed form $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\ln\cos x\over \tan^sx}\cdot\ln\left({\ln^2(\cos x)\over \pi^2+\ln^2(\sin x)}\right)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider $(1)$, once again the motivation of this question is from [Integral contest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985686/integral-contest)

> $$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ln \left(\cos x\right)}{\tan^s(x)}\ln \left(\frac{\ln ^2\left(\cos x\right)}{\pi ^2+\ln ^2\left(\sin x\right)}\right)\mathrm dx=F(s)\tag1$$
>   Where $s\ge1$

I noticed that 
$$F(1)=\zeta(2)\tag2$$

$$F(2)=3\zeta(3)\tag3$$

**How may one find the closed form of $F(s)?$**

Comment: $\ln^2 \cos^2 x=(\ln((\cos x)^2))^2$ ?

Comment: @FDP If this is what the OP meant, in Desmos I numerically get $1.10316... \neq \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1.6449...$ [Here is a link confirming this with WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+pi%2F2+of+log(cos+x)%2Ftan(x)+*+log((log%5E2(cos%5E+2))%2F(pi%5E2%2Blog%5E2(sin%5E+2))))

Comment: @FDP after playing around with it for a while, I think the OP meant $$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ln \left(\cos x\right)}{\tan \left(x\right)}\ln \left(\frac{\ln ^2\left(\cos x\right)}{\pi ^2+\ln ^2\left(\sin x\right)}\right)dx$$

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake posting  thank you so much editing it

Comment: What about $s=3$ ?

Comment: I have not idea @Zaid. Do you think there is a closed form for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not be able to contribute to this question. I am very busy.

Comment: I really like your new update of your blog. Very interesting. I hope I will benefit from it.

Comment: @Latte' As $x \to 0^+$, the integrand is such that $$\frac{\ln \left(\cos x\right)}{\tan^s \left(x\right)}\ln \left(\frac{\ln ^2\left(\cos x\right)}{\pi ^2+\ln ^2\left(\sin x\right)}\right) \sim- \frac{2\ln x}{x^{s-2}}$$ yielding that the given integral is *divergent* for $s-2\ge1$ that is for $s\ge3$. Thus $F(s)$ does *not* exist for $s\ge3$.

Comment: @Latte', glad you liked it.

Comment: $F(2)\neq3\zeta(3).$